# React show/hide custom ContextMenu is lagging after toggling more than 2 times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-table

I want to know why my browser is lagging just from showing/hiding a custom Context Menu I've created.

I have a React Material table and customized in a way that right clicking opens a context Menu with a list of items from the property. It does as its expected but after showing and hiding the component a couple of times, the browser just freezes. Why does this happen? And is there anyway to stop this from happening or an alternative way to do this?

Note: I've already tried the contextMenu package and it doesn't work well with MTableRow override, which is why I'm doing it this way.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, forwardRef } from "react";
import MaterialTable, { MTableBodyRow } from "material-table";
import OptionContextMenu from "../OptionContextMenuComponent";

import AddBox from "@material-ui/icons/AddBox";
import ArrowDownward from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowDownward";
import Check from "@material-ui/icons/Check";
import ChevronLeft from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";
import ChevronRight from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import Clear from "@material-ui/icons/Clear";
import DeleteOutline from "@material-ui/icons/DeleteOutline";
import Edit from "@material-ui/icons/Edit";
import FilterList from "@material-ui/icons/FilterList";
import FirstPage from "@material-ui/icons/FirstPage";
import LastPage from "@material-ui/icons/LastPage";
import Remove from "@material-ui/icons/Remove";
import SaveAlt from "@material-ui/icons/SaveAlt";
import Search from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import ViewColumn from "@material-ui/icons/ViewColumn";

const tableIcons = {
  Add: forwardRef((props, ref) => <AddBox {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Check: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Check {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Clear: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Delete: forwardRef((props, ref) => <DeleteOutline {...props} ref={ref} />),
  DetailPanel: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />
  )),
  Edit: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Edit {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Export: forwardRef((props, ref) => <SaveAlt {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Filter: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FilterList {...props} ref={ref} />),
  FirstPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FirstPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
  LastPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <LastPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
  NextPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
  PreviousPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <ChevronLeft {...props} ref={ref} />
  )),
  ResetSearch: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Search: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Search {...props} ref={ref} />),
  SortArrow: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ArrowDownward {...props} ref={ref} />),
  ThirdStateCheck: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Remove {...props} ref={ref} />),
  ViewColumn: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ViewColumn {...props} ref={ref} />)
};

const initialValue = {
  xPos: "0px",
  yPos: "0px",
  showMenu: false,
  options: []
};

//Show menu based on mouse position

const MyTable = () => {
  const [contextMenuProp, setContextMenuProp] = useState(initialValue);
  const onHandleContextMenu = (e, props) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newOptions = { ...contextMenuProp };
    newOptions.xPos = `${e.pageX}px`;
    newOptions.yPos = `${e.pageY}px`;
    newOptions.showMenu = true;
    newOptions.options = props.data.options;
    setContextMenuProp(newOptions);
    console.log("Right clicked", contextMenuProp);
  };

  // Re-hide menu
  const handleClick = (e, props) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newOptions = { ...contextMenuProp };
    newOptions.showMenu = false;
    newOptions.options = [];
    setContextMenuProp(newOptions);
    console.log("Left clicked");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <MaterialTable
        title="Dummy table"
        icons={tableIcons}
        columns={[
          { title: "Name", field: "name" },
          { title: "Surname", field: "surname" }
        ]}
        data={[
          { name: "Mehmet", surname: "Baran", options: ["work", "sleep"] },
          { name: "Zerya Betül", surname: "Baran", options: ["run", "walk"] }
        ]}
        options={{
          search: false,
          toolbar: false,
          paging: false,
          sorting: false,
          draggable: false,
          selection: false
        }}
        components={{
          Row: (props) => (
            <MTableBodyRow
              {...props}
              onContextMenu={(e) => onHandleContextMenu(e, props)}
            />
          )
        }}
        onRowClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}
      />
      <OptionContextMenu contextMenuProp={contextMenuProp} />
    </>
  );
};

export default MyTable;
```

The optionContextMenu component just displays what options are being passed.

Sample sandbox: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-goldwasser-wbdly?file=/Component/MyTable/index.js)

Comment: Can you create a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io)?

Comment: Added the sandbox. And although it works there in the sandbox, in my local it is causing some lag. I'm not sure why in the sandbox it isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the similar issue. It appears that there is a memory leak bug in `material-table` versions higher than `1.67`. If a page with a table is rendered several times, it will be a memory leak. I would suggest you downgrade your `material-table` version.

See [this](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/2650) and [this](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/2727)

Comment: This resolved my issue after I downgraded to V1.66.0 so I'll mark this as the answer. But one thing I don't get is, I'm not re-rendering the table but my contextMenu Component instead. So how come this fixed my issue?

Or am I unknowingly re-rendering my table everytime I trigger a click action?

Comment: That's another interesting thing about react material-table.The table is fully rerendered on parent state update since version 1.53.0. See this https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/1265

Comment: I have looked into it, and downgraded to V1.52.0 but after checking the profiler it seems to still re-render after parent state updates. Since this is a separate issue, I'll look into it more. Many thanks!